# Multiple monitors spanning fullscreen. Which platform?

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display

we purchased a video wall installation (4x [LG 47WV30B](http://www.lg.com/global/products/digital-signage/special-display/LG-47WV30B.jsp)) connected to a Intel MacPro with 2x ATI [5770](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC742ZM/A/ati-radeon-hd-5770-graphics-upgrade-kit-for-mac-pro-%28mid-2010%29). Everything works fine, but we are not totally happy. We display a custom dashboard of our application, written in house and running in a browser. We want the browser to go fullscreen, with no title or tool bar whatsoever, and span the 4 screens completely. Lion (and Mountain Lion) fullscreen is only using 1 out of 4 screens, we can hide the bars (Safari, Chrome and Mozilla have shortcuts) and the system's Menu bar and dock with [this](http://moapp.tumblr.com/post/2558804142/menuanddockless), but we still have the tiny window title bar with the 3 buttons on the left. It's not a big deal, but it's annoying that I can't achieve what I want. I did some testing on Fedora and Windows7, and I can't find anything that will send ANY browser in spanning full screen with no bars/docks. Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Uhm I might get by with Linux, launching a browser with geometry parameter:

/usr/local/bin/opera-11.01 -geometry 1600x3200-0+100 %U

and then killing the Window Manager (it's kinda ugly). Based on http://superuser.com/questions/241094/how-to-fullscreen-application-across-both-monitors-of-dual-head-display

Answer (score 1):

The video cards you have support [eyefinity](http://sites.amd.com/us/business/products/pro-graphics/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-for-professionals.aspx).

That means they can treat several monitors as one single big screen. You could then 'full screen' your browser on this single huge screen.

This works under windows. 
According to [hardmac.com](http://www.hardmac.com/news/2011/03/07/mac-os-x-lion-supports-the-radeon-eyefinity) this is also supported from OS/X Lion onward.

What I did not find out if how this works with multiple cards. A reference AMD 5770 has 4 or 6 connectors. The 4 connector one supports up to 3 displays (2xDVI plus one DP or one HDMI). or 6 displays (6x mini display port).

Comment: Unfortunately, I think those cards are not eyefinity. They have 1xDVI and 2xMiniDP on board.

Comment: The eyefinity support in hardware does not depend on that specific number and typos of ports. As far as I know all 5770's can do it, and many do not follow the reference design. However Mac specific boards sometimes have a different BIOS on the GPU. Still, you should be able to check this in the manual of the card.